# Odd box framing on review page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Browsing the review page, I noticed a minor framing bug. On the right side of the *Review|* header, appears a small scroll bar holder (see image below), as if that div’s height is bigger than its framing one.

[image]

And in fact, I can scroll its content.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next production build.